# How can I use jest and enzyme to test content generated dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

So, this component "Info" is a container which process some data in order to generate a "Details" children component with some props.

**Info.JS**

```
   import React from 'react'

import Details from './Details/Details'
import {Card} from 'reactstrap'
import classes from './Info.module.css'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const Info = (props)=>{
    let itemDetails = 'Item Details'
    let items = undefined
    if(props.activeTab === '1'){
        items = props.shortTerm
    } else if (props.activeTab ==='2'){
        items = props.mediumTerm
    } else if (props.activeTab ==='3'){
        items = props.longTerm
    }
    if(items.length!==0){
        itemDetails=(
            items.map((i,index)=>{
                if(i.id===props.itemIndex){
                    return <Details
                            title={i.itemName}
                            desc={i.itemDesc}
                            date={"Created at "+i.created}
                            edited={i.lastEdited}
                            key={index}/> 
                }
                console.log(itemDetails)
            return null
            })
        )
    } else{
         return itemDetails = (
                        <Details 
                        title="Title"
                        desc="Description"
                        key={null}
                        date={null}/>
                        ) 
    }

    return(
            <Card className={classes.info}>
                {itemDetails}
            </Card>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        shortTerm:state.reducer.items.shortTerm,
        mediumTerm:state.reducer.items.mediumTerm,
        longTerm:state.reducer.items.longTerm,
        activeTab:state.reducer.activeTab,
        itemIndex: state.reducer.itemIndex
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Info)
```

**Question**
How can I make a test in which I can check if any  component is being rendered? Or, how can I write a test in which I can check if any "itemDetails" is being rendered?

I tried this, so far, to test if I could find any  being rendered but it always return me a error saying "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined".
The test code is this one:

**Info.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {configure,shallow,mount,render} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import Info from './Info'
import Details from './Details/Details'



configure({adapter:new Adapter()})

describe('<Info />',()=>{
    let wrapper
    beforeEach(()=>{
         wrapper= shallow(<Info/>);
    })

    it('Should return one Details',()=>{
        expect(wrapper.find(Details)).toHaveLength(1)
    })
});
```

Comment: You say it throws an error on `find` there is no code in component that uses `find` I guess the `wrapper` is `undefined`.

To see answer your original question. I see `itemsDetails` is baed on `items` which in turn in based on the props you send. In your test case you are not mocking the store to the `Info` component so start by mocking the store so that your container picks it up. You can simply pass the store data using `store` prop for `Info`.

Comment: Yes, the wrapper is undefined! What do you mean with "itemsDetails is baed on items"? About the mocking store, I am gonna give it a go, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an answer,based on this one: [Testing React Redux - cannot read properties of undefined, or wrapper undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565280/testing-react-redux-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-or-wrapper-undefined)

It worked perfectly for me! I happens that, to generate the  component, I had to pass some props to the  component. This is the setup that I used in order to make the test to work:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {configure,shallow,mount,render} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import {Info} from './Info'
import Details from './Details/Details'

configure({adapter:new Adapter()})

const setup=()=>{
    let props= {
        shortTerm:[],
        mediumTerm:[],
        longTerm:[],
        activeTab:'1',
        itemIndex:0
    }

    let wrapper = shallow(<Info {...props}/>);

    return {props, wrapper};
};

describe('<Info />',()=>{
    const {wrapper}=setup()

    it('Should return one Details Component',()=>{
        expect(wrapper.find(Details)).toHaveLength(1)
    })
});
```